# Backbone How can i load only part of a json file into a collection

Tags: json, parsing, backbone.js, collections, fetch

Hi i have a json file that looks like this:

```
{
"links_1": [
    {
        "navn": "somename",
        "link": "http://www.domane.com"
    },
    {
        "navn": "somename",
        "link": "http://www.domane.com"
    },
    {
        "navn": "somename",
        "link": "http://www.domane.com"
    }
],
"links_2": [
    {
        "navn": "someothername",
        "link": "http://www.domane.com"
    },
    {
        "navn": "someothername",
        "link": "http://www.domane.com"
    },
    {
        "navn": "someothername",
        "link": "http://www.domane.com"
    }
]   
}
```

Then i have my Collection class.
Now i want to create a new collection that only contains the links_1 array from the json file.
And another new collection that contains the links_2 array from the json file.

How do i accomplish that?

```
var col = new Collection( Collection.prototype.parse = function(response){
return response.links_1;
}
```

So to illustrate further, i want my fetch to get specific json data objects.

```
var col = new Collection();
col.fetch(links_1);  //  here i only want to get links_1 json data

var col2 = new Collection();
col2.fetch(links_2); //  here i only want to get links_2 json data
```

any help would be great.

Comment: why dont you iterate over the collection and assign each "link" to a new collection variable ? col.forEach(function(model,index){ col = new Collection(model);  })

Comment: how about serving the appropriate content when requested ? you should only get what the collection needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with trying to override `parse`, you're just doing it incorrectly. Try:

```
//define a collection class
var Link1Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  parse:function(response) {
    return response.links_1
  }
});

//initialize a new instance of your collection class and fetch
var collection = new Link1Collection();
collection.fetch();
```

**Edit:** To select the field you want to extract on instance-to-instance basis, you can pass a custom option in the `fetch` options. The options are passed to `parse`:

```
//define a collection class
var LinkCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  parse:function(response, options) {
    return options.parseField ? response[options.parseField] : response;
  }
});

//initialize a new instance of your collection class and fetch
var collection = new LinkCollection();
collection.fetch({parseField:'links_1'});
```

Comment: I am aware of using fetch to get the parse response, but my question is about getting the full json data in the parse function. and then only showing part of it in the fetch.

Something like this:


var Link1Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
parse:function(response) {
return response;  // i want all the json data availabe here
}
 });

 //initialize a new instance of your collection class and fetch
var collection = new Link1Collection();
collection.fetch(response.links_1);

var collection2 = new Link1Collection();
collection.fetch(response.links_2);

Comment: Might just be me, Im new to backbone - but using your above method, im only getting 1 object returned. not the data array from the json file.
Perhaps i need to do some toJSON(); on the parsed response?
    parse:function(response, options) {
    return options.parseField ? response[options.parseField] : response;
  }

Comment: Arh my backbone and underscore files where outdated - so that was the reason my results where not working.. thanks for the help!

Comment: @MarcelHuss-Nielsen, which version of Backbone are you using? The fiddle uses 0.9.10.